# Describe stage returns the stage, but show stages like returns 0 rows

Tags: terraform, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm using the Chan Zuckerberg Snowflake Terraform plugin: https://github.com/chanzuckerberg/terraform-provider-snowflake

And trying to set up some stages. The plugin is running two commands against the warehouse when I try to import a stage:

`DESCRIBE STAGE "AIRFLOW_DB"."AIRFLOW_EVENTS"."NEW_CUSTOMER"`

and

`SHOW STAGES LIKE 'NEW_CUSTOMER' IN DATABASE "AIRFLOW_DB"`

The first query works and returns the stage information, but the second query returns no rows, and results in the plugin erroring. Does anyone have any idea why the second query returns 0 rows when the stage is shown to exist by the first?

Comment: Can you please edit your question to show your Terraform code as a [mcve]? It would also help if your question included the exact error output you get.

Comment: Does changing your SHOW STAGES to this help?  `SHOW STAGES LIKE 'NEW_CUSTOMER%' IN DATABASE AIRFLOW_DB`